# Web scraping using Beautiful Soup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, review

I used the following code to scrape the data from the website. This is the "page-wise scraping".

I am able to scrape the reviews but it's printing only 1st review of the page. I want all the reviews belong to the page. Providing code for the reference-

```
pip install bs4
pip install pandas requests BeautifulSoup4
#import necessary libraries
    
#import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

base_url = "https://www.consumeraffairs.com/food/dominos.html"
all_pages_reviews = []
  

def scraper():
    for i in range(1,6): # fetching reviews from five pages
        pagewise_reviews = [] 
        query_parameter = "?page=3"+str(i)
    url = base_url + query_parameter
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser') 
    rev_div = soup.findAll("div",attrs={"class","rvw-bd"}) 
    for j in range(len(rev_div)):
        pagewise_reviews.append(rev_div[j].find("p").text)
        for k in range(len(pagewise_reviews)):
            all_pages_reviews.append(pagewise_reviews[k])
            return all_pages_reviews 
    

#Call the function scraper() and store the output to a variable 'reviews'
reviews = scraper()
i = range(1, len(reviews)+1)
reviews_df = pd.DataFrame({'review':reviews}, index=i)
print(reviews_df)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to return after all for loops completed, so you must indent your return at the same level as the first loop

```
for j in range(len(rev_div)):
  pagewise_reviews.append(rev_div[j].find("p").text)
    for k in range(len(pagewise_reviews)):
      all_pages_reviews.append(pagewise_reviews[k]
return all_pages_reviews
```